# MLP always returns same predicted result

Tags: pytorch, regression, mlp

I am using pytorch to implement a simple multilayer perceptron. The input data I have is of 450 dimensions and output is 120. I have normalized my input data. I use MSE as my loss function and the training converged.

When I testing the model, I found that no matter what input is, the output almost always remains same (for all 120 dimensions). I have tried make the model simpler (2 hidden layers) or more complex (up to 7 hidden layers), but this still happened.

Here is how I build my model:

```
class MLP(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self, D_in, D_out):
    super(MLP, self).__init__()
    self.linear_1 = torch.nn.Linear(D_in, 1000)
    self.linear_2 = torch.nn.Linear(1000, 1500)
    self.linear_3 = torch.nn.Linear(1500, 1000)
    self.linear_4 = torch.nn.Linear(1000, 750)
    self.linear_5 = torch.nn.Linear(750, 500)
    self.linear_6 = torch.nn.Linear(500, 250)
    self.linear_7 = torch.nn.Linear(250, D_out)
    self.sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

def forward(self, x):
         
    x = self.sigmoid(self.linear_1(x))
    x = self.sigmoid(self.linear_2(x))
    x = self.sigmoid(self.linear_3(x))
    x = self.sigmoid(self.linear_4(x))
    x = self.sigmoid(self.linear_5(x))
    x = self.sigmoid(self.linear_6(x))
    y_pred = self.linear_7(x)
 
    return y_pred
```

Can anyone give any insights into this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you a) include a snippet of your code: so that people can observe what you did thus far b) use an implementation like sklearn's mlpregressor and observe the results of that, for comparison's sake

Comment: Thanks @Mercury! Code added, I will also try use the sklearn's model to see whether I can get some results.